# amd64, i386 (32bit / 64bit) - Which version to choose?

Tags: 32-bit, 64-bit

Can every CPU (in my case a Intel i7 890) install both of them ?
Amd64 and i386 ? I would like to install Ubuntu 64bit. So what is the right download ?

Comment: if you look at intels website http://www.intel.com/ . 

you will find all the information you need about your cpu!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your CPU can run both versions. Which version you install is more or less up to you, however, if your machine has at least 4GB of RAM, I would recommend installing the amd64 version. Some more insight into the differences between 32 and 64bit architectures can be found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7034/difference-between-32bit-and-64-bit). As for stability and availability, it [seems](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32202/is-64-bit-ubuntu-stable-for-general-use/32336#32336) you've already covered this in another question, so I won't go deeper. ;-)

You can get your download [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop/get-ubuntu/download). Choose 10.10, the latest version.

If you're in no hurry, you can wait about a month, then the next version (11.04 - Natty Narwhal) will be released, with [significant changes](http://unity.ubuntu.com/) to the default user interface. 
If you're a beginner you will save yourself some re-learning.

If you're especially patient, it may be good to wait another two weeks or so, then the worst, inevitable, bugs popping up at release will probably be fixed already, and your ride will be smoother.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, an i7 can run both the 32bit and the 64bit versions. It's just a matter of which iso to download: get the i386 one if you want a 32bits OS, and get the amd64 one if you want 64bits.

Answer (score 0):

Yes i7 works fine with both architectures, but no particulares evidences about performance. Usually a reason of this choice it's due about how much ram u have installed on board. If u need to map over 4gb 64bit works better, this one of main difference...

Answer (score -1):

If your processor is 64 bit use that one.
If you have an older machine that is 32bit use that one.
The 32 bit version will run on a 64 bit processor but not vice versa.
The 32 bit version will only support 2G memory. If you have more than
2G you probably have a 64bit processor.

Comment: 32-bit version can use up to 64 GB of RAM.