# Correct Ubuntu version for Intel i5 PC?

Tags: software-recommendation

I downloaded this ISO image `ubuntu-11.04-desktop-amd64.iso` to install on my PC later. My PC's CPU is an Intel i5, do I have the correct ISO image?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you look at intels webpage you can easily see if your cpu has 64-bit capability.  http://www.intel.com/products/processor/corei5/mobile/specifications.htm?wapkw=(i5)

You also need to specify what your model is called of your i5, you can find that by looking at your pc/mac model webpage.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/32402/amd64-i386-32bit-64bit-which-version-to-choose

Comment: Virtually all CPUs for normal desktop or laptop computers in the last decade are amd64 compatible.  There is no significant reason to use a i386 or x86 build in this day and age.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As for the CPU, your decision is right. Core i5 is a 64 bit capable processor, which is the amd64 version (please note that the amd is nothing to do with your CPU).

Answer (score 1):

you want version 12.04LTS or 16.04LTS LTS is long term support(5 years).
You won't be able to update 11.04 it's obsolete.

Comment: Why not 14.04.5?

Comment: You are responding to a question that is asked (5 years) ago.