# Version Ubuntu 12.10 for Intel

Tags: 12.10, intel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [amd64, i386 (32bit / 64bit) - Which version to choose?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32402/amd64-i386-32bit-64bit-which-version-to-choose)
>   [Difference between the i386 download and the amd64?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/54296/difference-between-the-i386-download-and-the-amd64)

When i want to start the download of Ubuntu 12.10 desktop 64 bit, it directly want to download the amd64 iso. Does this mean there is also a Intel version ? If so, where can it be found ? I have an Intel core2duo T9300 2.50Ghz processor so it can run the 64 bit version.

specs:
http://ark.intel.com/products/33917/Intel-Core2-Duo-Processor-T9300-6M-Cache-2_50-GHz-800-MHz-FSB

Thanks in advanced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"AMD64" is just a way of saying "64Bit", the i386 version is just 32bit.  I am using a Intel processor with AMD64 so it should work just fine.

My understanding is that AMD developed 64 bit first and got the right to call it "AMD64", so its all 64 bit and will work with your processor.

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry, Intel and AMD processors use the same versions.You must need to make sure to download the the ISO for the right architecture: 32-bit or 64-bit.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, you can run the AMD64 image on any 64-bit compatible processor, despite the vendor (Intel, AMD, etc.)

The AMD64 is *simply a naming convention* for disk architectures (e.g. 32-bit or 64-bit).
i386 is another example of this, it means that a processor has the x86 architecture.

Processor architecture is vendor-independent, so you can use programs compiled with an Intel processor on an AMD machine, and vice versa.