# Why does Ubuntu Download recommend 64-bit install?

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, 64-bit, 32-bit, architecture

Why would Ubuntu as a generalized statement recommend its 64 bit “flavour”?

As far as I understand a 64-bit OS can **only** be installed on a 64-bit hardware (CPU), i.e. 32-bit and 64-bit OS can be installed on a 64-bit hardware, but only a 32-bit OS can be installed on a 32-bit hardware (regardless of the amount of RAM available).

You can see this on the [download site](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop):

[image].

**EDIT**
I understand [the difference between 32-bit and 64-bit](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7034/what-are-the-differences-between-32-bit-and-64-bit-and-which-should-i-choose), and I see the pros and cons. For users with a 32-bit hardware this is not a question of choice. Recommending a 64-bit OS without taking into account the hardware is like recommending petrol over diesel and neglecting the engine. The download site does not check for 64 bit processor hardware, and *if detected* recommend a 64-bit OS, but recommends a 64-bit OS to all users (with more than 2 GB RAM).

It has been stated that ”manufacturers don’t really make 32-bit systems any more” (Dalton), and that “almost all chips in recent history are 64 bit” (oldfred). This is true at least for [processor families in TOP500 supercomputers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Processor_families_in_TOP500_supercomputers.svg). So this recommendation simply reflects a trend in industrial production?

Comment: You already paid for the computer. Ubuntu recommends the 64-bit architecture so that you get all of the performance that you paid for.

Comment: Old question, nearly the opposite: [Why does Ubuntu Download recommend 32-bit install?](http://askubuntu.com/q/1441/178596), also: [Is 64 bit Ubuntu stable for general use?](http://askubuntu.com/q/32202/178596), [What are the differences between 32-bit and 64-bit, and which should I choose?](http://askubuntu.com/q/7034/178596) . Both 32bit (and 32bit with PAE) and 64bit can be installed on 64bit hardware, only 32bit probably can be installed on 32bit.

Comment: @wilf 32-bit can be installed on 64-bit as well...

Comment: @Wilf I have seen and read the other question before posting, but they address a different subject. Thanks for posting the image in my question.

Comment: I know they address a similar but not the same issue, not me close voting it...

Comment: "a trend in industrial production" .... that and the fact that we  have UEFI support only in the 64-bit version.

Comment: According to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_microprocessors Intel introduced mainstream IA64 CPUs (not Itanium) in 2004, that's a full decade ago. And that was after AMD extended IA32 and showed Intel the way forward. IA64 has greater address space, double the number of registers, a more powerful instruction set, and more.  10 years should be long enough to adapt :)

Answer (score 10):

Most modern computers come with more than 4GiB of RAM, so you'd need a 64bit OS to use all of this. (Or 32bit with [PAE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_Address_Extension), which is slower) Also, most new machines are using UEFI, and Ubuntu 32bit ISO's aren't UEFI-capable, so here you'd have to go with 64bit

On older hardware, which doesn't use UEFI and/or has less then 4GiB of RAM, it doesn't matter, as long as the CPU is 64bit-capable, which most are.

Other than that, 64bit may be recommended for various reasons:

- You can run 32bit software on a 64bit CPU (multiarch), but not vice verca. So you may be better off with 64bit when talking about software compatibility.
- If people don't know the difference between 32bit and 64bit, the should choose the one that will run on the most systems with less problems, which probably is 64bit. Although someone might say that people should know the difference when installing an OS by themselves, I've met at least one person who wanted to install Ubuntu and had barely any clue of CPU architecture ("64bit is better, because it's the greater number" should indicate his knowledge)

There may be other reasons, but these are the ones I can think of now.

Comment: With 32bit [PAE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_Address_Extension) can be used for more than 4GB of RAM - I used to have this with nearly every flippin netbook.

Comment: @Wilf yes but that was merely a patch. Your system with PAE would be a bit slower. If you install the 32 bit you will still get PAE with 4Gb+ but why bother if the 64bit version is better in everything.

Comment: You can run a 32-bit OS on an UEFI computer. Just not Ubuntu, as the UEFI bootloader has not been put in the Ubuntu .ISOs. There are 32-bit only UEFI machines, and there are operating systems that have 32-bit versions that boot using UEFI.

Comment: @FuzzyToothpaste Really? Never heared of that. I'll include it in my answer. Coul you provide any example?

Comment: @the_Seppi an obvious example of a 32-bit OS that supports EFI would be the early versions of OSX for the Mac-intel platform.

Comment: @the_Seppi Solaris also does UEFI booting in 32-bit.

Comment: As an anecdotal example, my HP pavilion offers memory configurations that don't work with a 32 version of the OS.

Answer (score 0):

It recommends it because 64-bit is faster and today, manufacturers don’t really make 32-bit systems any more. It may also recommend 64-bit because the download site recognized that your pc is 64-bit (the one you are using to download the image). It also says 32-bit is for PC's with less than 2GB of ram because 99.9% of all PC's with less than 2GB of ram are 32-bit. Take it as you will, but 32-bit is being phased out and is mostly on old slow hardware. Ubuntu is not made for outdated hardware, I would use something like xubuntu or lubuntu if you planned on putting on on outdated hardware.

Comment: - You state that ”manufacturers don’t really make 32-bit systems any more”. What is your source e.g sales figures? 
- Assuming manufacturers had suddenly stopped producing 32-bit systems 3 years ago – how would this reflect in the number of systems *in use*? I have done a quick search and not been able to find any data on this. 
- I don't think the download site recognizes my systems's hardware – it's 32-bit... ;-)

Comment: @mariano purely from a logical point of view: any system sold with W7 or W8 will be 64bit. Do you still see new system in store that sell with another operating system?

Comment: @Rinzwind Yes I do see “new system[s] in store that sell with another operating system”, but I don't have numbers. So I can only  speculate. But maybe someone has them. Do you by any chance?

Comment: Ubuntu will be phasing out 32 bit with 16.04. http://summit.ubuntu.com/uos-1411/meeting/22353/when-should-we-stop-making-32-bit-images/ Note that almost all chips in recent history are 64 bit. There were only a few Atom's that were 32 bit more for Windows tablet type systems to try to prevent Linux installs: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64

Comment: The other reason for the recommendation of 32-bit on <=2GB RAM is that a 32-bit OS uses less memory in general, so even if the CPU is 64-bit, if the system is RAM-constrained, you might get more real-world performance (avoiding swapping) by running it as 32-bit.